# Make text input fields and their labels line up correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

Here's an excerpt from a fairly standard Rails form:

```
  <p>
    <%= f.label :from_station %> <%= f.text_field :from_station %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :to_station %> <%= f.text_field :to_station %>
  </p>
```

By default, this renders like this:

[alt text http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/127/picture6u.png](http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/127/picture6u.png)

This doesn't look great since the text fields don't line up. What's the easiest way to make the form look more like this:

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/746/picture7shk.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/746/picture7shk.png)

I've tried setting the `width` style property on the `<label>`s, but this property doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I have found that not placing each field on its own row, i.e. have from and to horizontally next to each other.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is more of a CSS question;

Labels by default aren't a block level element and so won't accept a width. Try setting this CSS:

```
label{
  width: 4em;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  display: block
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I wonder whether this solution will work in older browsers (like IE6, to name one). I think the table solution is more reliable...

Comment: Yes it will, and works better for screen readers and text-only browsers too. And search engines :)

Comment: @Jongsam: if you look for the myriads of questions and answers on SO discussing the wrong and right usage of tables in layouts you'll most probably conclude that you shouldn't use a table for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<table>` where each label is in column 1 and each textfield is in column 2.