# Convention for aligning rails form boxes

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the convention for aligning form_for input boxes? The form boxes below stagger with each different title length.

```
      <%= form_for @new_review, url: brand_beans_reviews_path(@bean.id) do |f| %> 
        User name: <%= f.text_field :user %>
        Drinking for: <%= f.text_field :experiance %>
        Brew type: <%= f.text_field :brew %>
        Caffeine: <%= f.text_field :caffeine %>
        Flavor: <%= f.text_field :flavor %>
        Overall: <%= f.text_field :rating %>
        <%= f.submit %>
      <% end %>
```

I tried using a span on my field titles and setting a width, browser would say its set but would not render the set width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for, this was more of a CSS issue I was having. I wasnt sure on how to address the title fields, but the link below used label encapsulate and address CSS to it.

[Make text input fields and their labels line up correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252477/make-text-input-fields-and-their-labels-line-up-correctly)

Comment: Accept an answer(this can be your own answer) so the questions goes to resolved.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one. There are as many ways of *displaying* a form as there are websites on the Internet, and it's completely up to you to figure out the styling for your own website. Rails imposes absolutely no conventions here.

Pick a front-end framework like Bootstrap or write your own CSS.